# How can I achieve this, using shortcodes

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I have a plugin that restricts contents for registered users only, on the other hand I have created a shortcode for showing a chat and I want to hide it using the restrictive shortcode;

[upme_private][chat][/upme_private]

But it doesnt work, what would be the best aproach?

The function to "Hide" restricted content uses;

```
function upme_private($atts, $content = null) {
        global $upme;
        return $upme->hidden_content($atts, $content);
    }
```

and the shortcode that i created is

> add_shortcode( 'barchat', 'barc_chat_script' );

Essentially what I want is to be able to hide the barchat shortcode from users by;

> [upme_private][chat][/upme_private]

But I dont know how to modify the return of the upme_private function to include do_shortcode() since its already returning another function (hidden_content)

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create Nested Shortcodes so at the end of your handler which looks like `function shortcode_handler($params, $content = null)` do this :

```
 return do_shortcode($content);
```

instead of :

```
return $content;
```

Comment: Indeed it has something to do with nested shortcodes